# Running glassfish from a USB thumb drive

Tags: glassfish, usb-drive

Is it possible to run glassfish from a USB thumb drive with no installation necessary? Anyone have a link to a tutorial or documentation about how to do this?

Similar Question:

[Running Tomcat from USB Flash Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491903/running-tomcat-from-usb-flash-drive)

Answer (score 2):

Assume we are talking about MS Windows. On the linux or other systems the steps are similar.

GlassFish depends on JRE, thus you also need to store JRE on the USB drive (or depend on system JRE). The easiest way to achieve this is to install JRE to your local PC and just copy the resulting directory from your "Program files". For example, copy "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7" to "X:\glassfish\JRE"

Then, you need to download GlassFish zip distribution and extract it to the desired folder, say "X:\glassfish".

The last thing to do is to configure GlassFish to use the JRE from USB drive. To achieve this, add the following line to the file "X:\glassfish\glassfish\config\asenv.bat"

```
SET AS_JAVA=\glassfish\JRE\
```

Now you may start your GlassFish server with the asadmin.bat start-domain command as usual. You could also create your own bat files for starting and stopping the server.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure about glassfish and USB drive. I ran NetBeans and tomcat from flash drive and didn't have a problem. I ran glassfish on several computers synced through the DropBox service, but that is different. I made many experiments with collecting a good development stack on a flash drive. For most of them I blogged about [here](http://nbide.blogspot.com). My suggestion is to take an OS independent packages for glassfish and some IDE (I work with NetBeans but eclipse should also be very able do the job) and extract them on the flash drive. You might need to copy a local JDK installation to the flash drive also. Once you get the IDE running, generally you'll only need to register the application server, and the IDE will let you manage it easily.
I hope this was clear :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run GlassFish4 from a USB Stick.
I just followed the steps from https://glassfish.java.net/download.html
 1. download the .zip
 2. unzip it to USB stick
 3. start the server(from the USB location). the start-up took some 1,2 minutes